# retrieving firebase data and saving it to shared preferences produces null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database on `firebase` from that I'd like to retrieve some data and save it to my app using `shared preferences`. When I try to get the value in another `activtiy` from `shared preferences` I saved before I get null. BUT the toast gets popped up with the right values.

I call getLocDbs() from `onCreate()`.

I tried `async task` but I read after that `Firebase` is async itself.

Why do I get null?

Thanks

```
 public void getLocDbs() {

    firebaseRef.child("rpi_lox").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Toast.makeText(Welcomer.this, singleSnapshot.getValue
                        (postObject.class).result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                allLox += singleSnapshot.getValue
                        (rpiLocTemplate.class).locName+ ";";

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Welcomer.this)
            .edit()
            .putString("ls_locations", allLox).apply();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Welcomer.this)
        .edit()
        .putString("ls_locations", allLox).apply();
```

inside `onDataChange` because the network call will take some time to finish and `onDataChange` will be called when response is received otherwise you are saving null in preference and data is being received later

```
 public void getLocDbs() {

    firebaseRef.child("rpi_lox").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Toast.makeText(Welcomer.this, singleSnapshot.getValue
                        (postObject.class).result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                allLox += singleSnapshot.getValue
                        (rpiLocTemplate.class).locName+ ";";

            }
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Welcomer.this)
            .edit()
            .putString("ls_locations", allLox).apply();
       }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

[`Do you have any idea, why my string begins with null?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966373/retrieving-firebase-data-and-saving-it-to-shared-preferences-produces-null/49966427#comment86948983_49966427)

you have declare string as `String allLox;` which will assign null value and when you do `+=` then it will append null in first iteration as

```
`allLox = allLox + otherstuff`
 // allLox = null + otherstuff
```

so declare your string variable as

```
String allLox = "";
```

or you can use `StringBuilder` while using `append` method to achieve efficiency

Comment: You're great, thanks very much! One question: Do you have any idea, why my string begins with null? The rest is good, I get everything I need.

Comment: probably yes, declare like `String allLox="";`  otherwise it will be null and `+=` mean `allLox= allLoc + other stuff`, i am glad that i could help

Comment: a similar error came up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063883/retrieving-downloaded-firebase-data-from-shared-preferences-produces-null Can you help me out? Thanks!